# Java headless GUI without java.awt.headless

Tags: java, awt

According to [this article](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/headless/), the only way to get headless operation is by setting `java.awt.headless`. I'm working on the implementation of a maven plugin and the code calls jfreechart, and it flashes my Mac's screen if I don't set headless. But it's not really polite for me to call `System.setProperty` (with global impact) in my maven plugin.

Is there any more tightly-scoped way to get headless operations?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could set the `<systemProperties>` for your plugin only within your plugin configuration in this way?

```
<configuration>
      <systemProperties> 
                         <property> 
                            <name>java.awt.headless</name> 
                            <value>true</value> 
                        </property> 
                    </systemProperties> 
</configuration>
```

Comment: That's about the same as putting a call to System.setProperty inside my plugin. WHich will work if no other plugin has initialized the toolkit and no other plugin wants, for some insane reason, to use actual graphics.